# Are you permitted to weigh Maror on Pesach night?

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada, melacha-creative-work

Are you permitted to use a mechanical scale to weigh the correct Shiur of Maror on Seder night?

Comment: Weight is probably not what you are looking for anyway http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6920/759

Comment: @DoubleAA According to those positions whom require about 25 grams of Maror, can one use the scale?  lol Thanks!

Comment: Like I indicated above most opinions hold that measurements are by volume not mass. So none of them (including prety much all ashkenazim) hold that marror is measured in grams.

Comment: @DoubleAA Many sephardim go by weight, even though the halacha is by volume, weight is easier to measure.  And the shiurim given for weight is much more than a kzayit would be anyways of either matzah or marror.

Comment: @Avi I said Ashkenazim for a reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch ([306:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=197)) rules that though one can generally not measure things on Shabbat and Yom Tov, one can do so for the purposes of a Mitzva.