# How many Oreos in a kezayis?

Tags: food, shiurim-measurements

For standard Oreo cookies, how many would be a kezayis by volume?  I have heard maybe 2.5 or maybe 3.

Comment: Too bad [the great Double Stuf experiment](http://blog.recursiveprocess.com/2013/08/20/oreo-verification/) measured only weight and not volume. ([Otoh....](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6920))

Comment: maybe helpful, a kezayis chart: http://www.zootorah.com/RationalistJudaism/MatzahMarorChart.pdf

Comment: 1 Oreo is bigger than any olive I've ever seen.

Comment: There is this book, but alas the cookie section does not have Oreos, or normal sized cookies, in the Amazon "look inside" http://www.amazon.com/Halachos-Kzayis-Yisroel-Pinchos-Bodner/dp/1583304894/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1393562492&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=kezayis

Comment: PTIJ: How many standard olives is a kezayis?

Answer (score 5):

According to the site [projectsbyjen.org](http://projectsbyjen.com/Projects/Oreo/oreo2002_facts.htm), the dimensions of an Oreo are 1.75 inches in width, and .314 inches in height. Since there's, surprisingly, not a lot of easy to find info on Oreo dimensions, let's go with this.
A k'zayis (according to [berachot.org](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/13_shiurkazayis.html), quoting Rav Bodner's "Halachos of K'zayis") is 28.8 cm³ (the most stringent view (I think), equal to half the volume of an egg.)

Math time!
1.75 in = 4.445 cm, and .314 in = .79756 cm.
The formula for volume of a cylinder is radius² × π × height.

```
(4.445 ÷ 2)² = 4.93950625 cm (radius²)  
4.93950625 × π = 15.5179165474 cm² (area of cookie face)  
15.5179165474 × .79756 = 12.3764695215³ (volume of cookie)  
28.8³ ÷ 12.3764695215³ = 2.32699639828³ (k'zayis divided by volume of cookie)
```

So! Approximately 2.3 cookies in a k'zayis, though because of empty space under the ridge, and the grooves in the cookie's design, maybe move it a little closer to 3.

Looks like you heard right. :)

Comment: ...according to the most stringent (=largest?) view. Can you include calculations for the more mainstream views?

Comment: @DoubleAA Basically, yes. Mishna Berura and "most poskim."

Comment: He only quotes them regarding bracha achrona. The question just asked about how many are a kezayis. Maybe the OP took a shevua to not eat a kezayis of oreo? How much oreo can he eat outside a sukkah? How many mint-creme oreos he can eat for karpas?

Comment: Should we exclude the creme from the height?

Comment: @HodofHod Incidentally, if you really want to be stringent you should eat 49.77 cm^3 (Chazon Ish) of Oreos, though at some point I imagine you'd just have to bentch already :)

Comment: @DoubleAA Actually, I'm so stringent that I don't eat Oreos. Except special runs. :D And then I make sure to eat at least 30. Cause I'm so stringent.

Comment: @hod is that a chalav yisrael joke? but oreos are pareve!

Comment: [continued in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14039891#14039891)

Comment: Maybe he wants to know how many Oreos he can have lying around over Pesach without having to do Biur?