Where is the netsiv regarding the size of a kezayis?
I heard recently that the netsiv of Volozhin holds that a kezayis is the size of modern day olive, or about 4 cc. Does anybody know where this netsiv can be found, and if this opinion is accepted lahalacha lechatchila by anybody/ any group, without being choshesh for other opinions?

Pretty sure everyone accepts this opinion. Most are machmir for other opinions too but I don't think anyone disagrees that this is the baseline ruling.

Perhaps the reference meant this https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40995&st=&pgnum=13 ?

@DoubleAA everyone accepts this opinion, including all those aiming to eat less than a kezayit of karpas at the seder?

@Joe Sure. That case is interesting though since what you want isnt really less than a kezayit but less than an amount for an after bracha. If you're regularly strict on safek bracha for an amount between a "real" kezayit and a "inflated" kezayit, then even after you've eaten a "real" kezayit you wouldnt say B"N anyway. Combine with the opinions that you shouldn't say an after bracha before maror (for good measure throw in that B"N on fruit may be reshut) and someone might allow that lechatchila. Frankly some might prefer it because you actually fulfill the mitzva for those that need a kezayit

@DoubleAA does that mean that people are careful to not eat between a netsiv-kezayis of food, and a machmir-kezayis, so as not to get into safek brachos problems? Because I don't think I've seen or heard/read about that

@DoubleAA where he says "...והוא שיעור קטן מאוד"? Could be, but I'd like a more accurate source than that

Loani There are lots of cases in theory where someone might want to pay attention to the smaller size https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35857/how-many-oreos-in-a-kezayis/35869#comment93454_35869 (cc @JoelK about mint creme oreos) but as you can see there most people don't care or bother. It just doesn't come up regularly enough apparently.

@DoubleAA could be. Either way, the person I was talking to claimed that he follows this opinion lechatchila, and from what I understood, without being machmir like other opinions, so that's more what I'm asking about. I'll edit to make that clearer.

This opinion is often quoted in the name of R Chaim of Volzhin, rather than the Netziv. Is it possible that that is what you heard?

@JoelK it's possible, but I don't think so... Also could be that the person I tried to quoted the wrong person
